# How to send an app invite of some another app using Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-invites

I am currently working on a Firebase-Android project which has two modules in it: one for the normal users and second for the Admin. I have added Firebase App invite feature in Admin module. But whenever it sends an invite, link mentioned in the message redirects to Admin module on the Play Store instead of redirecting to User module. So, is there a way in which one is redirected to User module even when invite has come from Admin module?

Comment: So, you're publishing two different apps on the store?

Comment: No not in that way. I have both of the installed on my phone. Whenever I click the invite link received from someone else's phone, Admin app opens up. I want User app to open up.

Comment: I don't think it works that way.  The intended use case for Invites is for users to invite other users into the same app that they're using.

Comment: Then there would be no use of having an invite feature on Admin apps. Wouldn't this be wierd?